# IE11 gives a "SCRIPT70: Permission denied" error when using window.location to reload the page

Tags: javascript

I have a page that has filters, when a filter is selected, the page is re-loaded using window.location with an altered querystring.

This is working in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Edge, but in IE11 I get a "SCRIPT70: Permission denied" error and a blank page.

However, this doesn't happen every time - it's intermittent!

This isn't an iFrame or cross-domain script issue - the page is reloading itself.

The code is simple - the onclick event calls a function, the function changes the querystring & then does:

```
window.location = "/search_results?" + qs;
```

Where qs is the updated querystring. That's it.

I have tried using the full URL (inc domain name) - no difference.
I have tried changing to window.location.href - no difference.

Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`location` is an object.

```
location.href = "address";
```

or

```
location.assign("address");
```

can help.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_assign.asp

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I've tried both and am still getting the error intermittently.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=window.location there shoud be another problem this is not a browser version issue.

Comment: Thanks Güven - your comment prompted me to look further & I found a separate issue! I'd made the mistake of focusing on this line when I should have proved it was ok & the issue was elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.location` instead of `window.location`